# jQuery counter from specified variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, counter

If I have the variables below

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var minsecond = 1;
    var maxseconds = 4;
    var updateinterval = 1;
    var interval = updateinterval*1000;
    window.setInterval(function(){
    var currentseconds = ; //value increasing by 1 every var updateinterval (value) in seconds  from var minsecond value until it reaches var maxseconds and resetting to var minsecond value and cycling again
    $("span").html(currentseconds);
    }, interval);
});
​
```

How do I create a counter which starts at value of `var minsecond` and goes up by 1 every `var updateinterval` in seconds to the value `var maxsecond`  and then restarting at  `var minsecond`
http://jsfiddle.net/TnNhA/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
var maxseconds = 4;
var updateinterval = 1;
var interval = updateinterval * 1000;

var counter = 1;

window.setInterval(function() {
    $("span").html(counter);
    counter = (counter % maxseconds == 0) ? 1 : counter + 1;
}, interval);​
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KVTvJ/1/)** Example

Answer (score 2):

I think something like below is what you want,

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/TnNhA/2/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var minsecond = 1;
    var maxseconds = 4;
    var updateinterval = 1;
    var interval = updateinterval*1000;

    var currentseconds = minsecond;

    window.setInterval(function(){
        if (currentseconds > maxseconds ) {
             currentseconds = minsecond;
        }

        $("span").html(currentseconds++);
    }, interval);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work for you?

```
var currentseconds = 0;
setInterval(yourFunction(), interval);

function yourFunction() {
  if (minsecond >= maxsecond) {
    currentseconds = minsecond;
  }
  else {
    currentseconds++;
  }
  $("span").html(currentseconds);
}
```

Set up a test to check if `currentseconds` it reaches your `maxsecond` var, reset it.

Comment: Watch out for the calling-in-`setInterval` gotcha.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it. The tricky part is the interval, as it is variable. In my answer I assume you aren't incrementing by whole numbers, but by your interval amount. Hopefully this is how you thought of it too.

http://jsfiddle.net/Vfnjh/1

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var minsecond = 1;
    var maxseconds = 4;
    var updateinterval = 1;
    var interval = updateinterval * 1000;
    var currentseconds = minsecond;

    window.setInterval(function() {
        currentseconds += updateinterval;
        if (currentseconds > maxseconds) {
            currentseconds = minsecond;
        }
        $("span").html(currentseconds);
    }, interval);
});​
```

Comment: Not currentseconds += updateinterval  From OP post "counter which starts at value of var minsecond and goes up by 1 every var updateinterval in seconds to the value var maxsecond and then restarting at var minsecond"